# Java only close base stream

Tags: java, stream

If I create a base stream

```
FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(...)
```

and then create some other streams around it:

```
ZipInputStream stream2 = new ZipInputStream(stream)

ZipInputStream stream3 = new ZipInputStream(stream)
```

And then close the base:

```
stream.close()
```

Is this sufficient if I'm done with all streams?  Or do I need to close the outer streams too?

*Edit*

Changed to zip streams to be clearer.

Comment: Depends on `SomeOtherSteam` I guess.. See the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#close()) to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

You should read the API ，I think if it should be closeed again depend on the construction method of the ZipInputStream ， if it retrun a reference of the base stream ，you would not close it again，but if it return a copy of the base stream ，I think you should close it again。The API would have some description of it。

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, Reading the API will provide more info.

An alternative would be to use Java 7's `try-with-resources`:

```
try (
    FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(...);
    ZipInputStream stream2 = new ZipInputStream(stream);
    ZipInputStream stream3 = new ZipInputStream(stream)
) {
    bw.write(text);
}
```

This feature has an implicit `finally` block that will close all resources that were declared in the brackets. Make sure that all streams implement `Closeable` and `AutoCloseable` when using this approach since the nested stream's close method may be called twice.